# disabled not working with formControlName into model-driven form in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I am using a model-driven template. I want to disable input if checkbox not checked.but it not working with formControlName.
I tried with three way. give here

```
 1.disabled="!filterForm.value.customer_limit"
 2.[disabled]="!filterForm.value.customer_limit"
 3.[readonly]="!filterForm.value.customer_limit"
```

this is my HTML code:

```
 <md-checkbox [checked]="filterForm.value.customer_limit" formControlName="customer_limit">
                        <md-input-container class="full-width">
                            <input mdInput
                                   formControlName="customer_limit_input"
                                   [disabled]="!filterForm.value.customer_limit"
                                   placeholder="Limit to customers">
    </md-input-container>
    </md-checkbox>
```

have any idea please help me. thanks

Comment: Your `formControlName="customer_limit"` and you are accessing as `[disabled]="!filterForm.value.customer_limit"`. You are using a additional `.value` which will be undefined

Comment: @ Aravind its not undefined. i check it.

Comment: Then whats happening. Create a plunker to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With reactive forms, `[disabled]` or `disabled` do not work. What you can use, is to check whether the checkbox is checked or not and disable or enable the input field.

First of all, I removed the input field from inside the checkbox, wasn't sure why it was placed there.

Then when building a form, I made an if-statement to check the value of `customer_input` and then disable the input field if it's false:

```ts
if this.myForm.get('customer_limit').value === true
  this.myForm.get('customer_limit_input').enable()
```

**IF** you though know the boolean value initially of the `customer_limit`, you can skip the above, and just disable the field initially (if that is the case), like suggested by Shailesh:

```ts
customer_limit_input: [{value: 'something', disabled: true}]
```

I put a change event to watch the status of the checkbox and call a function when changes happen:

```html
<md-checkbox (change)="disableEnableInput(myForm.get('customer_limit').value)" 
  formControlName="customer_limit">
</md-checkbox>
<md-input-container class="full-width">
  <input mdInput formControlName="customer_limit_input">
</md-input-container>
```

The `disableEnableInput()` function:

```ts
disableEnableInput(bool: boolean) {
  if bool === true
    this.myForm.get('customer_limit_input').enable()
  else
    this.myForm.get('customer_limit_input').disable()
}
```

I don't know if there is a more elegant solution for this (?) But this is what I have used thus far.

Here's **[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/x0R6HX9OW8Us61o8zh12?p=preview)**

Comment: You are very welcome! I think there isn't yet a better solution for this `disabled`-issue than to manually disable and enable, which might even be a little strange that there isn't. But furthermore, there is other options to watch for changes, other than `change`, you could use `valueChanges` like provided in another answer. I just prefer using `change`, but that is matter of preference! :) Have a nice day and haaappy coding! :)

Comment: actually in my form lots of checkbox so valueChanges method given full form data so i need to check all checkbox and then enable input. and change method give one specific checkbox change event so directly set enable disable. thats why in my case your answer is better. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In your component make sure you define a `boolean` variable to hold your input state:

```
  disabled: boolean = true;
```

and in your template you toggle it as the following:

```
<md-checkbox [(ngModel)]="disabled">Toggle Input</md-checkbox>
<input mdInput [disabled]="disabled">
```

**EDIT:** for model-driven forms, format your template as the following:

```
 <md-checkbox [formControl]="checkbox">Toggle Input</md-checkbox>
 <input mdInput [disabled]="disabled">
```

and in your component, you listen for changes just like this:

```
disabled: boolean;
ngOnInit(){
   this.checkbox.valueChanges.subscribe(val => this.disabled = val);
}
```

Comment: i using model-driven method. issue is disabled not working with formControlName

Comment: @ShaileshLadumor what's the error you get? Is your checkbox is inside a form or it is separate just like your template shows?

Answer (score 1):

i got solution from [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11271#issuecomment-244507976) set disabled with formControlName.

```
form = new FormGroup({
    'first': new FormControl({value: 'hello', disabled: false})
  })

ngOnInit(): void {
        this.filterForm.valueChanges.subscribe(
            (formValue) => {
               console.log(formValue)
            }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I was able to find

```
<input mdInput
       formControlName="customer_limit_input"
       [attr.disabled]="!filterForm.value.customer_limit ? true : null"
       placeholder="Limit to customers">
```